# Extracting one of the multiple similar tag 'named' values [Python-lxml]

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Below is the sample XML snippet. I need to get the value **"ABCD"**

**Sample.xml**

```
 <layer>
    <value>Random</value>
    <value>12345</value>
    </layer>
    <layer>
    <value>Last_Name</value>
    <value>ABCD</value>
    </layer>
    <layer>
    <value>dynamic</value>
    <value>a1234bcd</value>
    </layer>
```

**Sample.py**

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('sample.xml')
print tree.xpath('//layer[value="Last_Name"]/value')[0].text  #returns **"Last_Name"**
# Xpath : //layer/value[text()='Last_Name']/value # This also didn't work
```

How do i extract the value of one of the same tags ?

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. Do you want to get the contents of the first `value` element after the `value` element with content `Last_Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree.xpath('//layer[value="Last_Name"]/value')[1].text
```

the xpath will renturn :

```
[<value>Last_Name</value>,
<value>ABCD</value>]
```

the `ABCD` is in index 1

Answer (score 0):

Hello I've modified your XML file just a bit and enclosed it in one more tag called  tag

#

```
<data>
<layer>
    <value>Random</value>
    <value>12345</value>
</layer>
<layer>
    <value>Last_Name</value>
    <value>ABCD</value>
</layer>
<layer>
    <value>dynamic</value>
    <value>a1234bcd</value>
</layer>
</data>
```

#

now this is a sample python program.

#######Python Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file="filename.xml")

root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    for attr in child:
            if(attr.tag == 'value'):
                print(attr.text)
```